# How can I improve the downvotes of a question as an author?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

I asked a question on StackOverflow yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396342/java-diffie-hellman-key-exchange-implementation-gotcha

- Before asking I searched almost a day for solutions, including StackOverflow
- I phrased the question well (I'm not a native speaker, but my grammar is OK)
- Provided concept code
- Explained my motivations well
- It's definitely not a homework questions

Then someone came along and without any explanation, feedback or guidance downvoted the question.  This probably made people ignore it, and as another result it certainly get out of sight of many people who maybe able to potentially answer the question which is the goal of this entire site.

My question: can I somehow challenge a downvote? It ruins the usefulness of the site. We come here to solve problems.

(I asked my friends if there's anything wrong with the question. It is certainly not too specific, you can see many people struggling with Java DH implementations. It is specific maybe if that area is out of your knowledge, but than any such area could be "too specific = you don't know it". The other thing we could think of is that the person didn't read well, and thought that I need SSL, but that's not the case).

I'd like to see who actually gave the downvote, so I can get a feedback from the person to improve the question.

Comment: Well, in general ignoring down votes will serve you much better than putting angry disclaimers about them at the start of your question. That will probably only make things worse.

Comment: Maybe someone thought your question was too chatty.

Comment: How about *concisely* stating what the problem is?  That's a big wall of text without an immediate, obvious question.

Comment: The disclaimer and your corresponding edit message at the beginning of your question makes me want to downvote it without even reading it. I won't, but you might want to address that. Lashing out is never the answer, even if you're upset. And if it's feedback you're looking for from the downvoter, referring to them as a troll or moron is not going to make that happen.

Comment: I had to work very hard to not downvote the post when I saw that disclaimer as well.  I settled for simply removing it, as it shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Servy thanks for removing it, I would do that too

Comment: Bonus question gentlemen: why is this topic -6?

Comment: @CsabaToth http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta See the section on voting.

Comment: @Bart: thanks, I'm new to meta

Comment: nothing makes me want to downvote more than people complaining about downvotes

Comment: *"The other thing we could think of is that the person didn't read well, and thought that I need SSL"* -- why would you think so? And as apparently you do think such might happen: make clear that SSL is not the answer? (In a more friendly way than you did earlier.)

Comment: I restructured the whole question. Should I make the code snippet shorter too? (the problematic part is at the end)

Comment: Thanks anyone for helping with suggestions. I'm learning.

Comment: @CsabaToth I've edited your question a little. I understand you're writing in your second language, so don't feel criticized. Asking a question is not **opening a topic** and the distinction is important. SO is not for discussing. It's for asking something crisp, clear, and answerable. When a question is rambly, long, and hard to find the actual **question** it will get downvotes. This is a feature. While it hurts to get them, the fact they exist is what leads us to so many crisp, clear, answerable questions - and their answers.

Comment: @KateGregory Thank you, and it's an honor! I can say "SO - it's my foot"! ;)

Comment: I can also see the other big conclusion: I should take down-vote less seriously.

Comment: @CsabaToth No, downvotes are serious business, they just aren't *personal*.  It's not an insult to you, it's someone taking time to provide feedback on your post *so that you can improve it to provide better content*.  Think of it as a polite suggestion to re-read your post and either address the specific problems mentioned in comments, or if there are none, just for anything you think may be problematic.  You shouldn't just ignore downvotes, because they *are* serious.  What you shouldn't do is be offended by them; there is no malice in downvotes, merely constructive feedback.

Comment: I asked this question in 2013 more then 5 years ago when I was relatively new. Isn't it kind of funny and telling that this question itself is downvoted several times? it's almost like what I asked is a taboo and triggered people. I'm almost sure that some of the downvoters are downvoted because they didn't agree with the intent behind the question.

Obviously my main intent was to improve a question so it'd add value to the SO eco-system. And I'd like to gather feedback

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> can I somehow override/undo the -1?

No, you cannot.  Everyone has the right to vote however they want on any post, barring a few exceptions for cases of voting fraud.  You cannot undo the vote.

> Such cases ruins the usefulness of the site. We come here to solve problems, and such ignorant actions jeopardize that.

While downvotes that may seem improper can be problematic at times, the voting system adds far more value than the problems it causes.  Allowing you to just invalidate a vote because you don't like it would effectively be the same as removing the voting system entirely.

The ability for users to be able to downvote poor quality content is *essential* to the success of the site.

Comment: In short, good content overrides -1's.

Comment: *"the voting system adds far more value than the problems it causes"* -- including feeding the automatic post bans for those who post crap. So indeed: very much agreed.

Comment: I can see why the voting system is useful. I often see homework questions or such question I cannot understand (bad English).

Comment: @Servy, very well said - thanks.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't see who placed that downvote. Not even Community Moderators can do that. Votes are anonymous by design, and I don't ever see that changing.

People can vote up or down a question or answer for whatever reason they choose. Perhaps they thought your question was too easy. Perhaps they didn't like how you phrased it. Perhaps they don't like your avatar. People are *encouraged* to write comments to explain why think a post isn't up-to-snuff, but it isn't required.

All you can do is step back and see if there is a way to improve your question. If not, then just forget about it and move on. It's just one vote.

Of course, you've now brought attention to your question here on Meta. That may or may not work out for you. Good luck.

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't go look at your question before writing this.

Comment: Having read the question, I can say it wouldn't matter if you had.

Comment: It could be a feature maybe to ask the person anonymously (not knowing his identity) why was the down-vote. I see why it happened in my case, probably it was too lengthy, not clear enough/well focused.

Comment: Asking for anonymous feedback on downvotes has also been a requested feature. Cast about on Meta for a while. It has been discussed to death.

Answer (score 2):

**Answering your question...**

As for your "question" portion... Any attempt to "play" the system to counteract the -1 is going to be considered a breach of terms of use. Don't do it. You're not suppose to be able to.

**Moving Forward...**

Having taken a very quick glance at your question, you almost certainly triggered someone's `tl; dr.` response. That may have been manifested in the form of a downvote. Some questions can be summarized better, some need a ton of detail.

I might try to break up big walls of text or code by writing inline explanations for small blocks of code (instead of code comments, which make for a longer code block).

Some people are going to vote down because it's not interesting to them; I certainly can sympathize. It's also entirely possible that your topic is very niche, and will only benefit from a bounty.

One final thought: don't become too concerned about a negative score causing people to steer clear of your question. I'm quite the opposite; negative scores attract me to questions, so it may end up working out in your favor, in the long run!

Comment: Too long; didn't read.

Comment: answered my question: what is "tl; dr"

Comment: Understood, I should phrase the question shorter.

Comment: Could you have stated your entire question as:  I have a `byte[]` returned from `KeyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()`. How can I convert it to a `PublicKey` so that I can use it with `doPhase`?

Comment: Actually that's the essence. I thought I'll give as much background info as possible, but probably that can distract people from sorting out the real question. I could imagine that someone says that I'd rather have to export a X509 format certificate or something.

Comment: No problem; I guess I'd state the question first. After the basic question, offer more detail, a background, things you've tried, etc... but at least I can skip the rest, if I already have thought of an answer. Good luck with your problem...